# merge a scanned multi-page document into a single PDF (Windows) - no 3rd-Party

Tags: windows, pdf, printing, scanning, merge

In Windows10, I wanted to know how to merge a scanned multi-page document (the result was multiple images - 1 per page) into a single PDF without installing new/untrusted software.

My search for advice only yielded 3rd-party software recommendations. Other forums pointed people here so even though this forum is for the software recommendations I was looking to avoid, I am posting my question here because this is likely where it will add value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by

1. Selecting all the images I wanted to combine **
2. Right-click and select "print" and the "print pictures" dialog appears
3. select the "printer" as "Microsoft Print to PDF"
4. Select the "options" link (above the buttons in the bottom right corner)
5. Ensure your orientation is how you want it
6. Click "print"
7. The "print output as" dialog appears where you enter your new file name
8. Click "save"

** NOTE: the "print pictures" dialog kept ordering the pages/images as last page (page n), then page 1,2,3,...(n-1)
         the solution to this was to select pages/images 2 through n, then select page 1. this gave me the correct ordering. e.g. In My case selecting images 2,3,4,5,6,7,1

[image: instruction context]